# how to work with choose button in UIImagePickerController in iPhone library

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am new to iPhone programming .here i am choosing the iPhone library with UIImagePickerController ,but if i click on choose button it is not working how to work with that choose button in UIImagePickerController .So any one can help out this 
Thanks in Advance

```
videoPickerCtrl=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    videoPickerCtrl.delegate=self;
    videoPickerCtrl.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoPickerCtrl.sourceType];     
    videoPickerCtrl.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self presentModalViewController:videoPickerCtrl animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have you implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods?

Answer (score 1):

Makre sure you implemented the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods, as you are setting the delegate to self.

Here's a simple & great tutorial for the basics:

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/

and here's a good one from apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406-SW1